# how to solve could not find driver error in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have many posts in my database but when I go to the domain, I get the following error:

> could not find driver (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `posts` order by `created_at` desc limit 1)

##### Route

```php
Route::get('/', [PostController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('home');
```

##### `PostController`

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {   
        $expTime = now()->addHours(5);

        // cache latest
        if (Cache::has('latest')) {
            $latest = Cache::get('latest');
        } else {
            $latest = Cache::remember('latest', $expTime, function () {
                return Post::latest()->first();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The error is in the line `return Post::latest()->first();`. `pdo_mysql` is already enabled but I am still getting this error. My PHP version `8.2.4` PHP mode `LASPI`.

Comment: how did you confirm that `pdo_mysql` is loaded/enabled?

Comment: ISP Panel has section that called PHP and there you can check it if ``pdo_mysql`` enabled or no

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I am not going to solve your driver issue. But let me "beautify" your code just a little bit:

```php
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {   
        // cache latest
        return Cache::remember('latest', now()->addHours(5), function () {
            return Post::latest()->first();
        });
    }
}
```

Or, even "better":

```php
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {   
        // cache latest
        return Cache::remember(
            'latest',
            now()->addHours(5),
            fn() => Post::latest()->first(),
        );
    }
}
```

[`Cache::remember`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/cache#retrieve-store) automatically gets the value, if it has nothing, it will cache the resulting function return value, so no need to use an `if` or anything else.

---

Related specifically to your error, try running `php -m` (will show enabled modules) and `php -i` (will show phpinfo) in the terminal/console so you can see if you have everything enabled. You can also share the PHP config you have, but definitely you do not have it correctly enabled for PHP.